# How to simplify dot product in physics-package in maple?

Tags: physics, maple, dot-product

I am using physics-package in maple.

I have used FRW metric for calculating Einstein and Ricci tensors. 
And I defined some four-vectors and I wanted to calculate their dot product.
 But maple doesn't simplify A[mu]B[~mu].

However when maple simplifies G[mu,nu].G[~mu,~nu] , it gives 4. 
But when I define other four-vectors , it doesn't simplify them and writes them exactly as they were (e.g A[mu].B[~mu]).

I am sending pictures of a simple example in which I have defined similar four-vectors and done similar dot products to what I described. 
What should I do if I want maple to simplify the dot product of four-vectors that I define as it simplifies its own four-vectors?

[image: example]